# bulid query using subquery in find_in_set clause in laravel

Tags: laravel

I need assistance in building the below in laravel

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE find_in_set(id, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(m_id) FROM other_table WHERE m_id > 0))
```

Comment: have you tried DB::raw()

Comment: show your tables structure and explain what you expect to get after query. maybe it is possible via pure eloquent